# Prove that $|f(z)-f(0)-f'(0)z|\leq f(|z|)-f(0)-f'(0)|z|$ on unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, holomorphic-functions

> If $f$ is holomorph, defined on the open unit disk $\Delta$, such that $f^{(n)}(0)>0$ for all $n$, prove that for all $z\in \Delta$
>
> $$|f(z)-f(0)-f'(0)z|\leq f(|z|)-f(0)-f'(0)|z|.$$

*Attempt.* I thought of turning $f(z)-f(0)-f'(0)z$ into an integral expression

$$f(z)-f(0)-f'(0)z=\int\limits_{[0,z]}\big(f'(\zeta)-f'(0)\big)\,d\zeta,$$

but I am not sure how to this would lead me to the same expression (with $|z|$ instead of $z$).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is holomorphic, it is analytic. So, there are numbers $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ such that$$(\forall z\in\Delta):f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$$and, since $a_n=\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$, $a_n\geqslant 0$, for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. So\begin{align}\bigl\lvert f(z)-f(0)-f'(0)z\bigr\rvert&=\left\lvert\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n\right)-a_0-a_1z\right\rvert\\&=\left\lvert\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nz^n\right\rvert\\&\leqslant\sum_{n=2}^\infty\lvert a_n\rvert\lvert z\rvert^n\\&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\lvert a_n\rvert\lvert z\rvert^n\right)-\lvert a_0\rvert-\lvert a_1\rvert\lvert z\rvert\\&=f\bigl(\lvert z\rvert\bigr)-\lvert a_0\rvert-f'(0)\lvert z\rvert.\end{align}